# Why instance block changes are not reflected when passing the changed value to constructor

Tags: java

I just came across a scenario, which i never experimented with before -

```
public class InstanceBlocks {
    public static  int i = 5;

    {
        i ++;
        System.out.println("Inside first instance block "+ i);
    }

    public InstanceBlocks(){
        this(i);
        i++;
        System.out.println("Inside def const "+ i); 
    }

    public InstanceBlocks(int i){
        i =i*2;
        System.out.println("Inside param const "+ i);
    }

}
```

The o/p is -

```
Inside first instance block 6
Inside param const 10
Inside def const 7
```

Why is the parameterized constructor printing 10? The 'this' call is passing the value as 5, but isn't the value of i already changed before the 'this' call?

Comment: I do not reproduce your output. How exactly are you calling `InstanceBlocks`? It should print `Inside first instance block 6` (not 5) with `new InstanceBlocks();`.

Comment: No way that first line says `Inside first instance block 5` with that code.

Comment: *"Inside def const"* If you mean *default constructor*, that isn't a default constructor. It's a zero-params constructor, but not a default one.

Comment: Fundamentally, leaving aside specifics, the best way to learn the answer to this question is to **use your debugger and watch the code run**. Set a breakpoint on `public static int i = 5` and single-step from there.

Comment: But the real problem is that `i` is shadowed inside `InstanceBlocks(int i)` constructor.

Comment: Just because you are using parameterised constructor. The constructor `InstanceBlocks(int i)` is printing the value of local variable i not the global static variable i, that is still 5.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question (and btw not a duplicate of the linked question). It's NOT about shadowing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of execution here is:

- Evaluation of `i` inside `this(i)` (i is still 5 at this point)
- Object constructor
- Instance initializer (the block that increments i from 5 to 6)
- Execution of the body of the `InstanceBlocks(int)` constructor (the parameter has a value of 5 because of the first step, and note that the `i = i * 2` is modifying the parameter, not the field)
- Execution of the rest of the body of the `InstanceBlocks()` constructor

This is documented in [JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

The instance initializer is only executed once, because only one instance is being constructed.

To answer your specific question:

> The 'this' call is passing the value as 5, but isn't the value of i already changed before the 'this' call?

And the answer is "no, because the chained constructor arguments are evaluated before the instance initializer is called".

Comment: Thank you so much Jon Skeet , makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Wow, Jon, you're a genius! Thanks for the link especially!